# Can typeahead be implemented over a dynamically changing dataframe using shinysky?

Tags: shiny, typeahead, shinysky

I am trying to populate a Typeahead box in Shiny, using the ShinySky package in R.

I'm trying to extend [the example](https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky/blob/master/README.md), where the data used to prepopulate the Typeahead is hardcoded into the `textInput.typeahead` function:

```
textInput.typeahead(
        id="thti"
        ,placeholder="type 'name' or '2'"
        ,local=data.frame(name=c("name1","name2"),info=c("info1","info2")) #<- LOOK!
        ,valueKey = "name"
        ,tokens=c(1,2)
        ,template = HTML("<p class='repo-language'>{{info}}</p> <p class='repo-name'>{{name}}</p> <p class='repo-description'>You need to learn more CSS to customize this further</p>")
      )
```

Having a local dataframe defined in the middle of the function is not what I would like to do, as the example has done here:

```
,local=data.frame(name=c("name1","name2"),info=c("info1","info2"))
```

I would like to supply an argument to `local` that is a reactive object, which is created elsewhere in Shiny.

So far I've been unable to do so.

Here's my strategy for attempting to populate the Lookhead options dynamically using reactivity:

1) Let the user subset a dataframe using a slider.
2) Set up the Lookahead to read in the subsetted dataframe, using something like `,local=subset(DF)`
 3) Hope that the Lookahead works as it's supposed to.

Seems simple enough?  Here's a screenshot, where you can clearly see that the Lookhead doesn't appear underneath the user input of 111. Below is my code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinysky)
options(shiny.trace = F)  # change to T for trace

DF <- data.frame(ID=c("111", "222", "333", "444"), info=c("info1", "info2", "info3", "info4"))

runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("This is a test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    helpText("I couldn't live without StackOverflow"),

    sliderInput("range",
                label = "Pick how many rows you want in your dataframe:",
                min = 2, max = 4, value = 2, step=1),

    helpText("After subsetting the dataframe using the controls above, can we make the Lookahead work?"),

    textInput.typeahead(
      id="thti"
      ,placeholder="type ID and info"
      ,local=subset(DF)
      ,valueKey = "ID"
      ,tokens=c(1,2)
      ,template = HTML("<p class='repo-language'>{{info}}</p> <p class='repo-name'>{{ID}}</p> <p class='repo-description'></p>"))

  ),
  mainPanel(textOutput("text1"),
            htmlOutput("text"),
            tableOutput('table')
  )
),
server = function(input, output, session) {

  subsetDF <- reactive({ DF <- DF[1:input$range, ]
                         DF
                         })

  output$text <- renderUI({
    str <- paste("This is how many rows you've chosen for your dataframe:",
                 input$range)
    HTML(paste(str, sep = '<br/>'))
                          })

  output$table <- renderTable(subsetDF())

}
)
)
```